# Black screen with Video Mixing Renderer 9 (VMR9)

Tags: video, overlay, directshow, multiple-monitors, renderer

As part of a bigger project I do a mix with several video streams and and also alpha bitmaps. Therefore I have the need to use VMR9 and not the "Video Renderer". This works fine on many systems. But I got some reports from customers having problems with this rendering. They see a black screen. For a couple of days I have a system that seems to have also this wrong behavior. The special thing is: It's a Laptop with a secondary monitor. On the primary monitor it works fine here but on the secondary monitor there is no rendering, the connected window remains black (mode is windowless).

Now I found out I can reproduce this wired behavior very simple with GraphEdit on this computer: I just render the video capture filter of the internal camera to the VMR9 and can see exactly the same: On the first monitor it works, moving it on the second monitor blacks out the window.

It has nothing to do with the **moving** to the other monitor it self. (I know the filtergraph manager stops the graph and restarts it again). If I start on the second monitor I see nothing and moving it to the first one, voila I see the stream.

In some forum entries NVidia graphics hardware is suspected. But the Laptop uses Intel-Graphics.

If somebody could help...

[EDIT] In the link in the comment of VuVirt it is mentioned that overlaying on the VMR on a secondary Display isnt possible. I didnt found any further information to that issue. Does anybody know about it and can explain?

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue. Have you updated the video drivers?

Comment: It's up to date!

Comment: This might be of help: http://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.directx.video.narkive.com/sKclNLlj/vmr9-multiple-monitor-error